# Merit gem - Display a specific badge and the users who obtained it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, badge, merit-gem

I would like to create a method `badges#show` such as it is done here in [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/222/altruist) in which the selected badge is displayed and the users who have obtained it. I have created a `BadgesController` in which I have the following:

```
  # Find badge
  before_action :set_badge, only: %i[show]

  # GET /badges/1
  def show; end

  private

  # Set badge
  def set_badge
    @badge = Merit::Badge.find(params[:badge_id])
  end
```

In `merit.rb` (I am only displaying the code for the first badge below):

```
# Use this hook to configure merit parameters
Merit.setup do |config|
  # Check rules on each request or in background
  # config.checks_on_each_request = true

  # Define ORM. Could be :active_record (default) and :mongoid
  # config.orm = :active_record

  # Add application observers to get notifications when reputation changes.
  # config.add_observer 'MyObserverClassName'

  # Define :user_model_name. This model will be used to grand badge if no
  # `:to` option is given. Default is 'User'.
  # config.user_model_name = 'User'

  # Define :current_user_method. Similar to previous option. It will be used
  # to retrieve :user_model_name object if no `:to` option is given. Default
  # is "current_#{user_model_name.downcase}".
  # config.current_user_method = 'current_user'
end

Merit::Badge.create!(
  id: 1,
  name: 'just-registered',
  description: 'New member',
  custom_fields: {
    icon_tag: 'user',
    category: 'user'
  }
)

# More badges [...]
```

However, when I try to display the badge name by doing `<%= @badge.name %>`, I get the following:
`undefined method 'name' for #<#<Class:0x000000001290cc18>:0x000000000c8c9d10>`.

The **params** I am passing at the point I am calling the **badges#show** method is **1** (in the url: */badges/1*).

The following lines throw the same error:

- `@badge = Merit::Badge.find_by_id(params[:badge_id])`
- `@badge = Merit::Badge.find_by_id(params[:id])`
- `@badge = Merit::Badge.find(params[:id])`

If I change `@badge = Merit::Badge.find(params[:badge_id])` to `@badge = Merit::Badge.find(:id)` I get this: `Could not find Merit::Badge with key "id"`.

When I try to debug my code, here is what happens with `<%= debug @badge %>` in the view (with `@badge = Merit::Badge.find(params[:badge_id])`):

```
#<#<Class:0x000000000da762c0>:0x000000000af48a80 @keys=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49], @mapper=#<Ambry::Mapper:0x000000000af48f58 @klass=Merit::Badge(id, name, level, description, custom_fields), @adapter_name=:main, @indexes={}, @lock=#<Thread::Mutex:0x000000000af48d28>, @options={}, @hash={1=>{:id=>1, :name=>"just-registered", :level=>nil, :description=>"New member", :custom_fields=>{:icon_tag=>"user", :category=>"user"}} [...]
```

It displays a hash with all the badges I have in my initializer file `merit.rb`. I do not understand why the **id** parameter is not being passed by the controller.

`<%= @badge.find(1).name %>` in the view works fine however.

What have I done wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try this one:

@badge = Merit::Badge.find(params[:id])

Comment: @nattfodd I get this `Could not find Merit::Badge with key "1"`. I do have a badge with id=1.

Comment: Badges use ambry, so syntax might differ with ActiveRecord. See https://github.com/norman/ambry. You can use `find_by_id`: https://github.com/merit-gem/merit/blob/master/app/models/merit/badge.rb#L15

Comment: @TuteC I wrote the following lines:
`@badge = Merit::Badge.find_by_id(params[:badge_id])` & `@badge = Merit::Badge.find_by_id(params[:id])`
Both still throw the same error as previously mentioned.

Comment: @TuteC Writing the lines mentioned in my previous comments without `params` throw the same error.

Comment: Just to be clear, the error I get is this one `undefined method 'name' for #<#<Class:0x000000001290cc18>:0x000000000c8c9d10>`

Comment: Can you share your initializer, and what params is at the point where you call it? Might be strings vs integer issue, for instance. Also, can you query badges in the rails console like that?

Comment: @TuteC I updated my post, adding my *initializer* (I only added the first badge which is the one I try all the time), the **params** I am calling (which is **1**), and the various other options I have tried following the suggestions in the comments. As to query badges in the rails console like I do in my controller, writing `Merit::Badge.find(1)` returns:

`#<Merit::Badge id: 1, name: "just-registered", level: nil, description: "New member", custom_fields: {:icon_tag=>"user", :category=>"user"}>`.

I am not sure if this is what you were asking for but it does seem to work however.

Comment: @TuteC I have updated my post with some more information and other options I have tried. I hope it helps!

Comment: @TuteC Thank you for your help! I finally managed to find a solution. I was wondering if it was possible to use `friendly-id` with Merit? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work!

Here is my solution:

In `badges_controller.rb`:

```
class BadgesController < ApplicationController

  # GET /badges/1
  def show; end

  private

  # Set badge
  def set_badge
    @badge = Merit::Badge.find(params[:badge_id])
    @id = @badge.keys[params[:id].to_i]
    @badge = @badge.find(@id)
  end

end
```

Then in the view `show.html.erb`, it is possible to call the usual methods as per the documentation:

```
<%= @badge.name %>
<%= @badge.description %>
<% @badge.users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.full_name %>
  <%= (user.sash.badges_sashes[params[:id].to_i].created_at).to_formatted_s(:long) %>
<% end %>
```

For information, the path must be `badge_path(badge.id - 1)` to redirect to the correct badge (arrays start at 0).